# Different height for each item in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

My client has developed a iPhone app that has a photo gallery with photos that have different heights, so the gallery looks something like this:

[image: Gallery Template]

I'm asked to do the same on Android so I have been trying to do this with the GridView but with no luck, I'm even starting to believe that this is not possible in Android!

My question is, is this possible to do using the Gridview in Android?

Comment: So you **want to** display the grid in an irregular size and not in a uniform size?

Comment: Yes exactly, if the gridview contains three columns, they always start at the same point, it is not possible to make each column start after the previous column has ended.

Comment: Hmm.. This is new. And I was almost about to post code for uniform size. That would have been a down-vote magnet. Unless someone can offer you a some help, let me see if I can cook something up.

Comment: I dont know why this is so hard in Android, I think the GridView widget does not support that at all and I need to get the source code for it and modify it myself. I downloaded the GridView.java but it references to other files in Android.Internal.R in the Android source code which is a pain to find them

Comment: I think they just did this on pinterest. Fancy has also done a gridview-ish implementation, but this time with irregular widths. I am starting to think that this could only be achieved by creating custom layouts.

Comment: Hi AmjadoV, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Wayne, I'm afraid mahkie was right, currently this cannot be done using any class in Android SDK, you have to do it manually aka inherit the Gridview class and override functions till you get what you want. I didnt have time to do that so I did it the GridView way.

Comment: There are nice realization this issue : https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo Looks very pretty.

Comment: Do you need to add these image dynamically or could you do it statically? If static, you may be able to use a ScrollView with ImageViews that you manually arrange in the staggered pattern you want. This of course will not offer the View recycling advantageous of a normal GridView.

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed, but I am using a StaggeredGridView to achieve this right now, works like a charm.

Comment: it's too cool! : https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Comment: As someone has said, you could easily have achieved this using linear layouts.  The elements had uniform widths, therefore three linear layouts.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a Masonry-View and it won't be too easy to achieve it since there isn't too much helpful stuff out there right now.

There are [some](http://code.google.com/p/android-masonry/) [libraries](https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall) available but when I tried them some months ago they didn't satisfy my needs and I dropped the idea to use a Masonry. But you could give it a try. Maybe they improved or in between some better stuff is out there.

Comment: I would just put vertically oreiented LinearLayout's within a horizontally oriented LinearLayout. I don't see why this is such a big deal, nor why the question was closed...

Comment: This may be suitable for some use cases but it general (i.e. for endless scrolling) you want the Android SDK Adapter API and - even more important - its internal view recycling. Without it you'll overflow your memory in no time and/or have a 2 fps scrolling experience.

Comment: So your saying to use a view that subclasses BaseAdapter (I think its called) ?

Comment: How about: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html